# Loading a part of view using a PHP variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am loading a part of view in by main view using a PHP variable 
here is the code of the view

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="gallery">
      <?= $view_thing ?>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and my controller is

```
$data['view_thing']=$this->load->view('model/portion',$data); //$data gets data from model
$this->layout->view('model/model',$data);
```

but the problem is "$view_thing" do not show things in the div in which I wrote it, this page is shown below body tag

note:I have wrote only a part of code from my view

Comment: Have you checked `$data['view_thing']`? `var_dump($data['view_thing'])`

Comment: Just try assigning like `$data['view_thing'] = $data`;

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL whats that, what will it do?

Comment: `$data['view_thing']` may be `null`. Check value before you say "it is showing nothing"

Comment: $data['view_thing'] is not null, view is being displayed on main page, but not at correct place

Comment: Are you sure you're not echoing the `$view_thing` before you assign something to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view loader function needs a third argument to return it as a string, [as said in the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html), for example:

```
$data['view_thing']=$this->load->view('model/portion', $data, true);
```